# Summing a value of a key over multiple documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection named users with the following structure to its documents

```
{
    "_id" : <user_id>,
    "NAME" : "ABC",
    "TIME" : 53.0,
    "OBJECTS" : 1
},
{
    "_id" : <user_id>,
    "NAME" : "ABCD",
    "TIME" : 353.0,
    "OBJECTS" : 70
}
```

Now, I want to sum the value of `OBJECTS` over the entire collection and return the value along with the objects.

Something like this

```
{
    {
        "_id" : <user_id>,
        "NAME" : "ABC",
        "TIME" : 53.0,
        "OBJECTS" : 1
    },
    {
        "_id" : <user_id>,
        "NAME" : "ABCD",
        "TIME" : 353.0,
        "OBJECTS" : 70
    },

 "TOTAL_OBJECTS": 71 
}
```

Or any way wherein I don't have to compute on the received object and can directly access from it. Now, I've tried looking this up but I found none where the hierarchy of the existing documents isn't destroyed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$group` specifying `null` as a grouping id. You'll gather all documents into one array (using `$$ROOT` variable) and another field can represent a sum of `OBJECT` like below:

```
db.users.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            documents: { $push: "$$ROOT" },
            TOTAL_OBJECTS: { $sum: "$OBJECTS" }
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $group: {
                _id: null,
                TOTAL_OBJECTS: {
                    $sum: '$OBJECTS'
                },
                documents: {
                    $addToSet: '$$CURRENT'
                }
            }
        },

    ]



);
```

Into above aggregate query I have pushed all documents into an array using [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addToSet/index.html) operator as a part of $[group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) stage of aggregate operation